# Remove df rows using information about unrepeated levels between two vectors

Tags: r

```
df <- data.frame(X = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "d" , "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), 
                  Y = c("w", "w", "w", "K", "K", "K", "L", "L", "L", "L", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z"))
```

Note that the first vector has 5 levels and the second has 4 levels. My goal is to select df lines that have all levels of vector 1 in common as vector 2. That is, I want to select lines that have levels "a", "b" and "c" since " d "appears only twice" and "appears only in vector 1.

I tried to make a list with the common levels and leave only the lines with the common levels by subset. However, it doesn't work because this level list doesn't generate the address of the lines I want to remove. Ex:

```
common <- c ("a", "b", "c")
df2 <- df [c(common),]
```

In my real df, there are 64 levels in common, so it doesn't happen "to do by hand". Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want. Essentially `split`ting `X` by `Y`, then looking for all `intersect`ing values that are in every set.

```
df[df$X %in% Reduce(intersect, split(df$X, df$Y)),]

#   X Y
#1  a w
#2  b w
#3  c w
#4  a K
#5  b K
#6  c K
#7  a L
#8  b L
#9  c L
#11 a Z
#12 b Z
#13 c Z
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way could be to `group_by` `X` and select groups which has all distinct values in `Y`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(X) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(Y) == n_distinct(.$Y))

#   X     Y    
# <fct> <fct>
# 1 a     w    
# 2 b     w    
# 3 c     w    
# 4 a     K    
# 5 b     K    
# 6 c     K    
# 7 a     L    
# 8 b     L    
# 9 c     L    
#10 a     Z    
#11 b     Z    
#12 c     Z
```

In base R, that would be using `ave`

```
subset(df, as.logical(ave(as.character(Y), X, 
          FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)) == length(unique(Y)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[uniqueN(Y) == uniqueN(df$Y)], by = X]
```